# Loading from AVRO to BigQuery - specify decimal type in the target table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, avro

I'm using  Google's Python SDK (https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html) to load AVRO files to BigQuery. Since there is a `BigNumeric` column in the data I need to specify the `--decimal_target_types=BIGNUMERIC` flag. Is there a way to do so in a `LoadJobConfig` object? I haven't been successful so far:

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './importer_google_credentials.json'

BUCKET_NAME = 'unique-bucket-name'
FILE_NAME = 'small-data-*.avro'

source_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME)
table_uri = "unique-table-name"

client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.use_avro_logical_types = True
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.AVRO
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.decimal_target_types = "BIGNUMERIC" #throws an AttributeError: Property decimal_target_types is unknown for <class 'google.cloud.bigquery.job.load.LoadJobConfig'>.

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    source_uri, table_uri, job_config=job_config
)
load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_uri)
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 26.05.2021 there seems to be no way to achieve what I want using Python SDK. I ended up using the `bq` command-line tool with the `--decimal_target_types=BIGNUMERIC`.